# PersistenceUnit configured in jar file has wrong PersistenceUnitRootLocation URL when imported in web-app context

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot Data JPA and Tomcat Starters,

I have an application with multiple Persistence Units defined in several maven modules which are working correctly when used standalone:

```
Project
-- IdentityAccess [PU name: identity-access]
|--- src/main/java
      |--- myapp.application [Application services using "identityAccessTransactionManager"]
      |--- myapp.domain.model [Entites classes]
      |--- myapp.infrastructure.persistence [Repositories Impl using nested DataJpa repositories]
|--- src/main/resources
      |--- myapp/application.properties
      |--- myapp/hibernate.cfg.xml
      |--- myapp/infrastructure/persistence/Group.hbm.xml
      |--- myapp/infrastructure/persistence/GroupMember.hbm.xml
      |--- myapp/infrastructure/persistence/User.hbm.xml

-- Promotion [PU name: promotion]
...

-- WebApplication [There is no PU here]
-> Depends on IdentityAccess, Promotion

@SpringBootApplication
@Import({IdentityAccessContext.class, PromotionContext.class})
```

Here is how I configure my EntityManagerFactoryBean in each PU giving them a unique bean name to avoid clashes. **Note: the following Configuration is a class contained in each modules**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        transactionManagerRef = TRANSACTION_MANAGER,
        entityManagerFactoryRef = ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY,
        considerNestedRepositories = true)
public class IdentityAccessPersistenceConfiguration {
    public static final String PERSISTENCE_CONTEXT = "identity-access";
    public static final String ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY = "identityAccessEntityManagerFactory";
    public static final String TRANSACTION_MANAGER = "identityAccessTransactionManager";

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean identityAccessEntityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactory.setMappingResources("myapp/identityaccess/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName("identity-access");
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager identityAccessTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

When I start each module individually, i.e. in test context but also as standalone application, entites are loaded and mapped correctly, the PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor has a root URL like this:

```
file:/F:/Workspaces/myapp/IdentityAccess/target/classes/
```

But when I start the web-app, each PU comes with another root URL, which is the root of the web-app context, thus it cannot load the mapping classes:

```
file:/F:/Workspaces/myapp/WebApplication/target/WebApplication-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/
```

Should it not be the jar containing the PU instead ? I tried to hook the setPersistenceUnitRootLocation to put my jar URL but i'm stuck since the version and path can obviously change. I don't even know if its a bug or if I am doing something not supported. Maybe this bug does not even belong to Spring Boot but Spring itself.

I feel that i'm touching a little bit too much internals that's why I think its a bug but please correct me if not I opened a ticket already on the spring boot github with the same description.

I also looked at:
    - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6983
    - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6635
    - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7003
    - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7021

which seems related.

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem:

In org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration, the method assumes the persistence unit is in the application itself:

```
private URL determinePersistenceUnitRootLocation() {
        Class<?> source = getClass();
        try {
            URL url = source.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
            return ResourceUtils.extractJarFileURL(url);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.info("Could not determine persistence " + "unit root location from "
                    + source + " : " + ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The source belong to the main webapp, so the class loader put the wrong path file.

To fix my issue this was a matter of setting the RootPersistenceUnitRootLocation with the same method in my configuration file using the configuration class from jar, and the unit has been loaded correctly from the JAR.

The question is: should spring boot autoconfigure use the class from the persistence unit instead, or maybe play with the setJarUrl to include a proper fix ? Or is it a determined choice to support only one main persistence unit ? I think it would be great to auto configure and allow out of the box multiple persistence units (coming from different jars) especially for Domain Driven Design architectures.